# Is it possible to use RealProxy to expose class interfaces over Remoting without MarshalByRefObject?

Tags: remoting

Is it possible to make a `RealProxy` that looks like this:

```
public InterfaceProxy(object instance, params Type[] interfaces)
```

and can expose all these `interfaces` over remoting, delegating calls to `instance`, even if an instance is not a `MarshalByRefObject`?

Currently I am having a problem where proxy receives a call to `InitializeLifetimeService`, and whatever I return from it (including `null`), I am always getting a following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException:Return argument has an invalid type
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.ValidateReturnArg(Object arg, Type paramType)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PropagateOutParameters(IMessage msg, Object[] outArgs, Object returnValue)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnmessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just have your class implement [IRemotingTypeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.iremotingtypeinfo.aspx).

pseudo-code looks like:

```
class InterfaceProxy : RealProxy, IRemotingTypeInfo
{
    // snip all the basics

    bool IRemotingTypeInfo.CanCastTo(Type fromType, Object o)
    {
        return interfaces.Contains(fromType);
    }
}
```